# Power BI Embedded - filtersApplied event not firing

Tags: powerbi-embedded

Using the [Power BI Playground](https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/dev-sandbox?showApi=reportRenderedEvent) I have added the event handled `filterApplied` and it does not fire.

```
report.on("filtersApplied", function () {
    console.log("filtersApplied");
});
```

I get the same issue in my Angular App with my event wired up as ( other events work )

```
eventHandlersMap = new Map<string, (event?: service.ICustomEvent<any>) => void>([
  ['filtersApplied', (event?: service.ICustomEvent<any>) => console.log('filtersApplied', event)],
  ['loaded', () => console.log('Report has loaded')],
  ['dataSelected', (event?: service.ICustomEvent<any>) => console.log('dataSelected', event)],
```

I expect the code to fire when the user uses the filter on the right hand pain :

[image]

This issue is also discussed on the [Microsoft Power BI Community Forum](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/filtersApplied-event-does-not-trigger/td-p/702344)

**How do I detect when the user changes the filter and I also need to
know what filter has been selected.?**

I am trying to export a report as PowerPoint but apply the filters that are selected in the report view. There maybe another way to achieve this.

This is an App owns data

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

```
const report: Report = this.reportObj.getReport();
const filters =  await report.getFilters();
```

This will output the selected filters, the event still does not fire but I can use the report render event and then read the filters, or just get the filters before I export my report.